# Why am I getting a 404 error when making an Axios post request even though my server is properly connected?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm not sure why I'm getting a `404` error even though my endpoint URL is correct.  I know it's correct because I've even verified through via the Network tab.  I'm testing via Postman and the API's working fine but some reason, the endpoint just can't be found.

I've tried too many ways to list here in an attempt to rectify this but to no avail.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to do to fix this?

I've tried `/api/register`, `api/register`, `/register` to name a few but none of it worked.

```
const LoginSignUp = () => {

const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

const handleSubmit = () => {
    let data = {
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'confirmPassword': confirmPassword
    }

    axios.post('http://myWebsite.test/api/register', data)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}


return(
 <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>
                                    <div className="card-back">
                                        <div className="center-wrap">
                                            <div className="section text-center">
                                                <h4 className="mb-4 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" name="logname"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Username"
                                                           id="userName"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-user"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="email" name="logemail"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Your Email"
                                                           id="logemail"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="password" name="logpass"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Your Password"
                                                           id="logpass"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                    <input type="password" name="logpass"
                                                           className="form-style"
                                                           placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                                           id="logpass"
                                                           autoComplete="none"
                                                           onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
                                                    />
                                                    <i className="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <button className="btn mt-4">Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
   );
}
```

Here's my api.php file

```
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

Here's the cURL format:

```
    curl 'http://myWebsite.test/api/register' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IjBLQ1Z2ck5DZ1NZSTUwQkNrOFoxaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV1MwaUVqM1NiYUdwcHcxSUlJMkhOMlIyeXZaaWdCOXEzd2ZFRFRkM3I0akVkQmJPSFJwYkM4cGc2WEhVYXBtM0xzV3FZQmxGWGpUUnoxMndBRkpzSlBWcFkwZVROTDhMTWpEWHNVc2RYYmpXVEgzdWo0NzI0RWlzM0FUWDJZek4iLCJtYWMiOiJhMDBiNzg0NDA4M2UyOGNmODQ0NjMwN2FlOWY3OTI5ZGZkOTkwNmUzZDA5OTliMDcxNjFkMGExOGJlNzUzYWI5In0=' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Origin: http://myWebsite.test' \
  -H 'Referer: http://myWebsite.test/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjBLQ1Z2ck5DZ1NZSTUwQkNrOFoxaWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiV1MwaUVqM1NiYUdwcHcxSUlJMkhOMlIyeXZaaWdCOXEzd2ZFRFRkM3I0akVkQmJPSFJwYkM4cGc2WEhVYXBtM0xzV3FZQmxGWGpUUnoxMndBRkpzSlBWcFkwZVROTDhMTWpEWHNVc2RYYmpXVEgzdWo0NzI0RWlzM0FUWDJZek4iLCJtYWMiOiJhMDBiNzg0NDA4M2UyOGNmODQ0NjMwN2FlOWY3OTI5ZGZkOTkwNmUzZDA5OTliMDcxNjFkMGExOGJlNzUzYWI5In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik9rdmowVnVGc0I5eXN0M043MmdmYWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieXVtSWtlSW5wOVRCWm1DM3FJdzJWSWduczRERk03MUFvN2U2czd5ZldUcXJ0Zi9wZUVpSU9mOE5UN3BNN3oraXdwSjlXNlhwL0VsNWl2aHprZ25leWxLWDZkMnpibXlrTkFZRDFLa3BQaVd2RFFZY3htTHZTUHZoMHJPeDNYWGEiLCJtYWMiOiJmM2EzMjdhMzI4MjZjZjA5NTJmYjFjNDA4OWNmYTYxZDUxYzdkOTk3OTQ1ODFlYTNhN2E4MGE1ODQ5ZWZhNDliIn0%3D' \
  --data-raw '{"name":"g","email":"","password":"","confirmPassword":""}' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

Comment: To clarify does the route also not work in postman?

Comment: @BenGooding The route does work Postman, which's the strangest part of all this

Comment: It would help to debug if you send the request your sending in postman (cURL format probably useful, but you can also export it to "NodeJs - Axios" format as well

Comment: @BenGooding I'm using PHP as backend, I'll grab the cURL format and post it here.

Comment: I mean you can export exactly what your sending in postman, assuming that works it shouldn't matter what your backend is

Comment: @BenGooding gotcha.  I've posted my cURL call in my original post.

Comment: Are you sure the 404 error is related to the URL?  I ask because certain issues, such as a `ModelNotFoundException`, will also throw a 404 error.

Comment: It's related to the URL because when I'm making a post request in Postman, it's working fine.  But for whatever reason, the endpoint url isn't being found in my code

Comment: The point I was attempting to make is that it is possible an issue in the `RegisterController` could be giving the false impression that the endpoint was not found by throwing a 404 error.  It just doesn't make much sense that a hard-coded URL would not be found when it is known to be visible to Postman.

Comment: what is the error you're getting? Are you getting any response from controller?

Comment: @Jayant When I submit the form, I get a 405 error that says `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`.  This makes no sense because my route's clearly a POST request.

Comment: What is the prefix you have added in routes.php? Have you tried to run `php artisan route:clear`